# Как исправить рекурсию?

Tags: python-3.x, рекурсия

Дана функция. Надо найти посл. чисел (без пробелов), что выведется при вызове F(4). Ответ: 4321021

```
  def F(n):
        print (n)
        if n > 2:
            F(n − 1)
            F(n − 2)
            F(n − 3)
```

Самый простой способ (как я и сделал), это заменить вывод: print(n, end=''). Ответ совпал.
Но затем я модифицировал функцию, при вызове print(F(4, '')) выводит 4324314304241 .

```
def F(n, l):
    l+=str(n)
    if n > 2:
         return F(n - 1, l) + F(n - 2, l) + F(n - 3, l)
    else:
        return l
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в использовании параметра `l`. Лучше вообще без него:

```
def F(n):
    if n > 2:
        return str(n) + F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) + F(n - 3)
    else:
        return str(n)
```